# How do C/C++ programs get ported to different platforms?

Tags: c++, c, porting

Java applications can run on different platforms because they always run on top of a Virtual Machine specifically developed for each platform. So, there's no native installation, you just drop the compiled jar anywhere and run it.

Now, I'm not very familiarized with the details of C/C++ development. So I'm curious, how do C/C++ programs get ported to run natively on different platforms? What would be the general steps to:

1- Write a program with a GUI that simply displays the words "Hello World" on a window.

2- Package it so that on Windows OS, it gets installed by running an installer (.exe file).

3- Package it so that on Linux, it gets installed with the `apt-get` command on a console.

4- Package it so that on Mac OSX, it gets installed by dropping it on the "Applications" folder.

What library would I use to display the "Hello World" window? How would this library have been written to make it work on several platforms? Are there different versions of this library for different platforms? If so, does that mean that every time I were to package the program for a specific platform, I would have to compile it using the specific version of the library for the specific platform?

I'm just trying to get a general understanding of how this process works. It would be nice to hear some go-to tools that C/C++ developers generally use for the packaging process.

Comment: They take cross-platform framework and parametrized build engine. see Qt tutorials.

Comment: Are you naive enough to believe in the old commercial slogan about Java: "write once, run everywhere"? I don't know much about Java in practice (but read most of its specs), but I am not naive enough to believe that real-world Java applications can run on various platforms without any pain.

Comment: `apt-get` probably don't work on Fedora, Redhat, Mageia ... linux distributions (but only on Debian & Ubuntu, etc...)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch You don't know much about Java but I do. And yes, you can run a Java application anywhere. As easy as executing a file. It's the whole concept the framework was built upon and it works flawlessly. How someone can trash something without knowing anything about it is beyond my comprehension.

Comment: A Java program which uses `"c:\\user\\data.txt"`  as a file path won't run on POSIX systems (e.g. on Linux). And there is a well known dependency hell with Java too....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Anyone who uses absolute paths on any kind of application deserves hell. There's no platform that can help someone like that become a better developer. There are no dependency hells in Java. Any library built on Java can be used on any Java based software. Of course, you cannot use a library specifically targeted for Android on a desktop application for example, but the reasons for hat are obvious.

Comment: My point is then that you can write unportable Java code, and you can write portable C++ code. Portability is orthogonal to the language, it is mostly a mindset.

Comment: I've heard on several occasions about dependency nightmares on Java.

Comment: software recommendations are explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic] (it's the same here as at Stack Overflow). See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: @gnat: I don't see any question about *particular* software recommendation. I understand more this question as being quite general.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch per my reading, it does: "What library would I use to... It would be nice to hear some go-to tools that..." (FWIW I tried to [edit] these bits out prior to commenting but it turned too "tightly coupled" with the question)

Comment: Isn't that just an  example?

Comment: these, as you call them, "examples" make a wide open door for posting spammy recommendations as legitimate answers, without any chance to flag these for moderator deletion

Comment: My answer don't have any software recommendations but gives some explanations, so I believe it fits here.

Comment: your answer looks okay to me, I wasn't talking about it

Comment: Check the answers here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/257550/how-do-i-compile-my-software-for-all-platforms-from-ubuntu-linux-64-bit/257574#257574

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two separate issues:

- How to code a C or C++ program which can easily be [ported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porting) to several operating systems. The easiest way is to use some cross-platform framework library like [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) (or perhaps [libsdl](http://libsdl.org/) or [GTK](http://gtk.org/)) which has been ported to several platforms and provides a common set of abstractions. You could also restrict yourself to *purely* [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) or [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) standard conforming code -without any external non-standardized library (but then, there are many applications that you won't be able to write, see e.g. [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/288015/40065)). Notice that the [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) specification exists (but has nothing for GUI applications!), if you follow it, your code should be able to be compiled and run on all POSIX compliant (a.k.a. [Unix standard](http://www.opengroup.org/standards/unix)) operating systems (e.g. [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) & [MacOSX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X) & [AIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX), etc..., but not [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows)). Otherwise, you would use conditional compilation (`#if` preprocessor directive) and hopefully wrap all operating-system specific services in a few translation units (to be used by the rest of your code).
- How to [package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_%28package_management_system%29) & [deploy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_deployment) a program (produced by compiling your C or C++ source code) on different operating systems. This is very OS specific, and even on Linux various [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) have different [package managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager): you'll have to do different things for Debian and for Redhat (and perhaps even different things for various versions of Linux distributions), since Debian has [`*.deb`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29) packages installed with `apt-get` or `dpkg` but Redhat has [`*.rpm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager) packages installed with `yum` or `rpm`! However on Linux the FHS ([filesystem hierarchy standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)) is helpful since it defines where files of your software should go (but how they are installed is still distribution or package manager specific).

It might be actually simpler & wiser to develop and distribute your program as a [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) in source form (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/)), and to expect (advanced) users and sysadmins to install it by compiling its source code (then running some installation script which would copy the binary at specific places, e.g. under `/usr/local/bin/` and the configuration files at other specific places, e.g. under `/etc/`, etc...). Eventually your free software might become packaged in most Linux distributions, and some external contributors would provide patches to enhance your code (or port it to some other operating system).

The [dependency hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell) may always become an issue (because you might need some specific versions of specific external libraries) - and it does not depend much on the language, you could have it in Java too! -, but package managers are more or less dealing with it.

[Portability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability) (which is relative to some specification) is mostly a mindset or an ideal: A well known quote (I forgot the attributions) is "*there is no portable program, there are only some programs which have been ported to some target systems*" (and that is true for many programming languages, including Java).

BTW, some programs get compiled to a plain [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) binary (only), other are requiring configuration files, external resources (e.g. fonts, graphic images, web or text templates, data files, script files) or dependencies. So the complexity of their deployment may vary a lot. For example, installing and deploying [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) (or [firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) browser) is very different -and much more complex- than installing a command line "hello world" program (which is nearly always a single executable). A graphical Qt-based "hello world" program is probably simple to install, if you assume that the target system already has the *right* version of Qt appropriately installed (in a usual place & configuration).

<sup>NB: notice that the C or C++ standards does not require that the implementation runs on a computer (in principle, you could unethically use a bunch of human slaves for a standard conforming C99 or C++11 implementation), and does not require a compiler. But most implementations are compiled (some few C interpreters exist however).</sup>